# Using Refit in ْXamarin the portal project

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, refit

I'm tying to use Refit in Xamarin portable project
I'm developing using Visual Studio for Mac OS and whenever I try to build I get this error

> The type or namespace 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net'. Are you missing 'System.Net.Http' assembly reference

I have noticed that the System.Net.Http assembly is not the .Net Portable as in the windows version of the framework
And I know I can not download it using NuGet as the package manager wouldn't recognize the portable framework and wont all to install

Comment: Did you install refit to all of your (relevant) projects? I see there are few issues on github but they are all resolved https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit/issues/250

Comment: @Milen I don't think the described issue in the URL is relevant to me as I can't even compile the code

Answer (score 0):

Install the NuGet package Microsoft.Net.Http